# Regulators lm75xx in series : 12v to 5v

Tags: voltage-regulator, heat, series

What do you think about puting regulators lm75xx in series in order to get less heat loss as possible :  9v-- to 5v-- to 3.3v , to get 3.3v from 12v supply? 
The idea is to not using a switching regulation or lm317 regulation direct regulator

Comment: Pretty much literal duplicate, only thing that is different is 24V supply, a 12V supply should be easier to build a linear reg circuit because there is less power to dissipate

Answer (score 0):

The total heat loss of your proposed series connected scheme is the same as the orthodox single linear regulator. But the losses in each linear reg are lower which can be useful on SMD boards where heatsinking is limited. I have seen this done before.